# What is the score of a post?

Tags: support, score

How can we know the score of a post? Is it counted by number of user upvotes or it is counted with the normal reputation score?

Comment: Score is total number of upvotes minus downvotes. Not the same as reputation, though affected because of upvotes and downvotes

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Currently here is the score of your question:

[image: score]

To know the score of your post just look at the number beside it.

It is calculated by:

> number of upvotes - number of downvotes